# How to justify a thermodynamic cycle practically?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have been working on some new thermodynamic cycle and was managed to create the formulation and the P-V diagram for it but when i showed my work to my professor he said that i am gonna have to practically justify my work but i don't know how would i do it.Can someone tell me how to practically show the justification of any thermodynamic cycle?

Comment: what exactly do you need to justify? It cannot be the existence of the cycle itself

Comment: I have to show that the formula and the diagram  i made match with each other and satisfies .

Comment: why it can't be the existence of the cycle?

Comment: because any cycle you can draw can exist, it does need any justification. But the clarification is enough. the answer depends on what variables he wants to justify, for instance, if it is the total efficiency of the cycle, you need to compute work done and heat exchanges, for every step in the cycle.

Comment: He wants to know what cyclic process of a useful physical system is approximated by the curves you've drawn. What kind of engine/refrigerator/heat pump can be built that is better described by your cycle than some other cycle *and* what advantages does that engine/refrigerator/heat pump have over existing designs.

Comment: On a P-V diagram I can draw any closed curve I want and claim that it is a thermodynamic cycle. But, not all (in fact very few) of those closed curves would consist of a (fairly) small number of easily obtained process that can be instantiated in an actual mechanical machine.

Answer (score 1):

To justify your cycle, you need to consider the followings,

1. is the first law valid? i.e. energy conserved
2. is the second law valid? i.e. for an isolated system, is entropy increasing?

There are many cycles designed violate second law which may not be obvious. You draw PV diagram. This is good. What about draw some other diagram such as T-s diagram for your cycle?

Comment: I'm confused by what you've stated here. If you draw a cycle in a $p$-$V$ diagram, the cycle will automatically satisfy both the second and first laws, assuming you have a proper equation of state. Drawing the cycle in the $T$-$s$ plane doesn't introduce any new information; it's merely a different description of the same thing. Can you clarify?

Comment: for example, you can use p-V diagram showing an isobaric expansion process, which is fine. But if you further claim this is an adiabatic process, which is not shown in p-V diagram, then the process is not practical.